# How to apply css on one html file only

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm building a website with AngularJS. And I'm using Plangular in order to create a customized Soundcloud Player. So I include my template like this :

```
<body>
  <div id="container">
   <div id="header" ng-controller="HeaderCtrl"><div ng-include="'templates/Header.tpl.html'"></div></div>
   <div id="body" ng-view></div>
   <div id=""><div ng-include="'templates/Player.tpl.html'"></div></div>
   <div id="footer" class="center" ng-controller="FooterCtrl"><div ng-include="'templates/Footer.tpl.html'"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

So as you can see I got a header, a body and a footer. In the middle of it I got a player. I included the specific CSS file in that template and only in that template, but the CSS are in a way applied to my whole page. I need those css. ANd I thought that included the css only on that page would help, but it's not.

Thanks for your help guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just prefix the CSS rules

Player.tpl.html :

```
<div class="player"> whatever </div>
```

CSS

```
.player .someclass {

}

.player .some-other-class {

}
```